# Unable to Iterate over Hashmap using java8

Tags: iterator

The below given is snipet of the ccode i am facing trouble with and i am using jdk 8. I am facing error in the bold line of the code , for loop statement. I have mentioned the error too.:

do {

```
            jobid = br.readLine();
            metajson = br.readLine();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(metajson);
            System.out.println(jobid+" "+obj.toString());
        //The below one should work 

            ****for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : obj.entrySet())****

            {

                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            }

        }
```

**Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    PropertyEntry cannot be resolved to a type
    Duplicate local variable entry
    Entry cannot be resolved to a type
    at com.journaldev.json.Insert3.main(Insert3.java:64)
a error at this line that says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry>"**

I tried the Property.Map() and concept.Map() too, but the same issue is there. I also imported the whole collection class too. But i don't know the error is not resolving.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Why do you expect a `JSONObject` to be a `HashMap<String, String>`?

Comment: i am using simple-json library and i am using jsonobject to parse the text file that contains lots of key value pairs in a single set of braces. I am using parser to seperate them. I am using iterate for the same reason as there are more than 2000 such records through which i have to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned set of entries has a type of `<String, JSONObject>` instead of `<String, String>` .
The following code compiles:

```
Set<Entry<String, JSONObject>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();

    for (Entry<String, JSONObject> entry : entrySet) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        JSONObject innerJsonObject = entry.getValue();
    }
```

Anyway that library (simple-json) has a bad design. JsonObject inherits itself from HashMap raw type (without filling it's generic type declaration) so the resulting entrySet's type is not known at compile time.

Tip: Use [GSon](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or other json library instead of that.